# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\log(x^2)}{1/x}$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\log(x^2)}{1/x}=0$ (where the result is 0 because from hierarchy of infinities we know that $1/x$ goes to infinity faster than $\log(x^2)$)

Can I solve the limit in this way without using de l'hospital? To do: tell me if my idea is right.

Comment: You literally said a way without L'Hospital's rule: "where the result is 0 because from hierarchy of infinities we know that 1/x goes to infinity faster than $log(x^2)$"

Comment: I would like to know if my idea is right...

Comment: @Forester my question is: my idea is right?

Comment: Than your question is very confusing!

Comment: It 's easy: either what I wrote is wrong or it is entirely lawful. I want only to know the correctness of what I have written

Comment: You're essentially asking two questions. "Can I solve the limit in this way without using de l'hospital?" and 'Is my idea right?'

Comment: @willie, The essence of L'hospital's rule is the same that you have written. Basically, what do we do in L'H rule? We differentiate up and down, that is we compare their slopes, that is, we check the rate of change is more for which thing. You have done the same thing without using the rule.

Comment: @1613585 These two questions are internally linked ... if the first answer is no the second question clearly doesn't make sense ... it's not nice to be so judicious ... I edited the question

Comment: @LightYagami thanks a lot! Exactly what I wanted to know!

Comment: Well, you have to *explain* what the "hierarchy of infinities" means and you have to explain *how* we know that $\frac 1x \to \infty$ "faster" than $\log(x^2)\to \infty$ does.  If we can do that you method is fine but... what does any of that *mean*?  You have your work cut out for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't want to use L'Hopital's rule, but we can use it to check:

The top one's derivative is $\frac{2}{x}$ (assuming your $\log$ is the natural log, but it works either way because change of base adds a multiplicative constant)

The bottom one's derivative is $-\frac{1}{x^2}$.

$\frac{2}{x} * -x^2$ = $-2x$.

And we can plug in $x = 0$ to get $0$. So yes, it is correct!

---

Note that your "hierarchy of infinities" directly follows from the essence of L'Hopital's rule, so you're essentially reinventing the wheel here.

Comment: "So yes, it is correct!"  That doesn't follow.  You can get a correct answer by incorrect methods.

Answer (score 0):

But *why* is the hierarchy ordered as stated? I think that's a proof in the wrong direction. With $y:=-\ln x$, note$$\lim_{x\to0^+}2x\ln x=2\lim_{y\to\infty}ye^{-y}=0$$because $\int_0^\infty ye^{-y}dy=1$ is a finite integral with continuous non-negative integrand. Then use that $x\ln(x^2)$ is odd.